# Why didnt Genos' core fuse with its past version?

Tags: one-punch-man

In One Punch Man manga chapter #168,

> Saitama returns to the past and fuses with his past self. His clothes also fuse, so the naked Saitama by fusing with the dressed Saitama appears with a suit which is half complete, with a hole in his private area. So if Saitama (human/organic) and clothes (inorganic) fuse with their former versions,

Why didnt Genos' core fuse with its past version?

Comment: Since this is the latest chapter to date, we can only presume the question will be addressed in further chapters...

Comment: @RigaCrypto there are several other possible answers such as, a logical explanation, an answer by one of the authors, Murata in particular uses to answer questions from fans and sometimes he gets back with an answer from One, a continuity mistake, etc.

Comment: Sure, but if the answers spoils something that is about to happen or be explained in the manga, he won't answer... that is why I said that we could get an explanation with the story is progressing.